# What is the probability that one of the events happens? 4 event

Tags: probability

Suppose there are $4$ events such that:

$P(A)$,$P(B)$,$P(C)$,$P(D)$

What is the probability that one of the events happens?
My answer is: $$P(A)+P(B)+P(C)+P(D)-P(A\cap B\cap C)-P(A\cap B\cap D)-P(A\cap C\cap D)-P(B\cap C\cap D)+P(A\cap B\cap C\cap D)$$

Does it sound right?

Thanks

Comment: Hi! First off, your question, is unfortunately, not worded well. However, I shall address the gist of the question - No, your answer is not right. However, what if you had, say, 10, or maybe 20 events in question, or maybe even more? Do you know of a more concise way to express your answer?

Comment: Sorry, thanks for the infor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note quite right, you are missing out intersection between two sets. Hence, the signs are wrong for some terms.

[Inclusion-exclusion Principle:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)

$$\mathbb{P}\biggl(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i\biggr)  =\sum_{k=1}^n \left((-1)^{k-1}\sum_{\scriptstyle I\subset\{1,\ldots,n\}\atop\scriptstyle|I|=k} \mathbb{P}(A_I)\right)$$

where the last sum runs over all subsets $I$ of the indices $1,\ldots , n$ which contain exactly $k$ elements, and

$$A_I=\bigcap_{i\in I} A_i$$

denotes the intersection of all those $A_i$ with index in $I$.

Comment: Since the question isn't super clear, you might want to mention the formula for exactly one of the $A_i$ happening.